# web application running on k8s cluster giving null when using request.getCookies() or request.getSession()

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am trying to run web application developed using Java, Jsp, Servlet, Angularjs and Jquery on K8s cluster.
While login into the application line which have **request.getCookies() or request.getSession()** hit, it is returning **null** and then it will throw **NullPointerException**. This exception is not allow me to login in to the application.

I have tried running the same application in local machine and on azure using docker and it is working fine. This confirms there is no issue in image . Following command used to run on docker,

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 <image_name>
```

I am using k8s on Azure(Azure kubernates service) and following is the configuration I have used.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app
  namespace: default
  name: app
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
      name: http
  selector:
    app: app
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: <image_name>
          name: app
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: app
```

All the pods, services and ingress are running normally without restarting or throwing any exception.

I tried creating **ingress** as well, but **issue is still same**. Following configuration I have used to create an ingress and also changed **service.spec.type** to **NodePort** before deploying the ingress.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gateway-app
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /app/*
            backend:
              serviceName: app
              servicePort: 8080
```

Please guide here how can we run applications with sessions and cookies on k8s cluster.

Comment: Hello @Sagar, welcome to Stack Overflow. Looks like session affinity (aka [sticky sessions](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/)) is perfect for want you want, you may want to look into this.

Comment: Hi @PawełGrondal, session affinity will be used for sticky session. In my case session is not getting established.

Comment: Hi @Sagar Joshi, have you found a solution?